# Can we get some horrible off-topic edits added to the audit set?

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, scope

Edits to off-topic (I mean that in the most limited way.  Not "substandard" or "fails to meet requirements" or "out of scope" but really not programming related in the slightest) questions are bad edits.  They waste reviewer time, without advancing our goal of building a repository of programming Q&A.  Editors should not be rewarded for pushing garbage through the queue.

The correct review action when presented with such an edit is to reject it, then go visit the question and vote to close.

Can we please get some audits to help drive this point home?  Here's a good first candidate:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6348656

Comment: I doubt there is a human factor involved at all, based on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168374/bring-a-human-factor-into-review-audit-composition-selection) that asks for the opposite of your feature-request....

Comment: @rene: That feature request wants to have zero audits created purely automatically.  The opposite of *zero* is not *all*, it is *some*.  And that is the current status -- some are created automatically, but some are created by moderators.  In any case, even if that candidate is not manually added to the queue, it serves as an example of what an automated algorithm should be looking for.  So what is your point?

Comment: Ok, didn't know moderators could mark posts to be used in audits, that is all....